# How to close the menu after click third layer menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

How to make the following CSS+js dropdown menu close after clicking third layer menu item. Now when I click anywhere outside the menu, it will close. I want click the third layer menu to close the menu.

This is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/donli/panzd/7/) example.

Html code:

```
 <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Please select</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu">
                     <li>
                         <a href="#">Artificial Turf</a>
                         <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" class="subMenu">Indoor</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="subMenu">Outdoor</a></li>
                        </ul>                    
                    </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Batting Cages</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" class="subMenu">Indoor</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="subMenu">Outdoor</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul​
```

CSS code:

```
/* 
    LEVEL ONE
*/
ul.dropdown                         { position: relative;color:#333;z-index: 9999; }
ul.dropdown li                      { font-weight: bold; float: left; zoom: 1; position: relative; }
ul.dropdown li a                    { display: block; padding: 8px 8px;color:#333;text-decoration:none;}
ul.dropdown li:last-child a         { border-right: none; } /* Doesn't work in IE */
ul.dropdown li.hover,ul.dropdown li:hover  { background: #CCC; position: relative; text-decoration: none;}

/* 
    LEVEL TWO
*/
ul.dropdown ul                         { width: 140px; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px;margin-top:0px; font-size: 12px;margin:0px;border: 1px solid #999;}
ul.dropdown ul li                     { font-weight: normal; background: #E5E5E5; color: #000;border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; float: none; margin:0px;padding:0px;padding-left:5px;}

                                    /* IE 6 & 7 Needs Inline Block */
ul.dropdown ul li a                    { border-right: none; width: 100%; display: inline-block;margin:0px; padding: 8px 0px;text-decoration:none;} 

/* 
    LEVEL THREE
*/
ul.dropdown ul ul                     { left: 100%; top: 0; max-height: 380px; overflow: auto;width:200px;}
```

Javascript code:

```
$(".dropdown li").click(function() { 
        $(this).parent().children("li").not(this).children("ul").css({ "visibility":"hidden" });
        $(this).children("ul").css({ "visibility":"visible" });
})

$('html').click(function() {
   $(".dropdown ul").css({ "visibility":"hidden" });
});

$('.dropdown').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
});


# this one not working
$('.subMenu').click(function(event) {
    $(".dropdown ul").css({ "visibility":"hidden" });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

​

​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this function.

```
$('.dropdown ul ul li a').click(function(event) {
   $(".dropdown ul").css({ "visibility":"hidden" });
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

It will close it on clicking the third layer and the event.stopPropagation() will disable reopening it again.

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nxtwrld/panzd/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `visibility:hidden` in your `CSS`, you can use `display:hidden` and then work with `hide()` and `show()` methods from `jQuery` like this:

**Live Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/panzd/13/

Then, this is just the only part that changes...

```
$('.dropdown').on('click', '.subMenu', function(event) {
    $(".dropdown ul").hide();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```